# How spa.proxy.json is generated when net6 single-page-application(spa) program build

Tags: c#, asp.net, single-page-application, .net-6.0

The new experience for SPA templates in .NET 6

A reference to the Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy NuGet package gets added to the ASP.NET Core project that contains the SPA project

The spa.proxy.json file is generated when the project is build

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A .targets MSBuild file is included with the package that does the generation, have a look here at the source: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/32e8c8cae5b1a4dd752d0a42a6f8a2813f75f173/src/Middleware/Spa/SpaProxy/src/build/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.targets

```xml
<Target Name="WriteSpaConfigurationToDisk" BeforeTargets="AssignTargetPaths">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <_SpaProxyServerLaunchConfig>$(IntermediateOutputPath)spa.proxy.json</_SpaProxyServerLaunchConfig>
...
```